# Logged response from axios missing values from API request

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using axios to call my API which responds back with a response as shown below:

```
{
    "name": "test-name",
    "attributes": {
        "innerAttributes": {
            "fundamentals": {
                "base": [
                    "sample-base-1",
                    "sample-base-2"
                ],
                "ref": [
                    "sample-ref-1",
                    "sample-ref-2"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Post getting the response from the API call, when I log the response into my console using below statement:

```
console.info("from API", response.data);
```

where response is defined as:

```
const response = await this.axiosInstance.get("my-ledger-endpoint/ledger-XXXXX");
```

I get the following logged into my console:

```
{
    "name": "test-name",
    "attributes": {
        "innerAttributes": {
            "fundamentals": {
                "base": ["sample-base-1"],
                "ref": ["sample-ref-1"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As it can be seen, the fundamentals object present inside `innerAttributes` key has base and ref values as only one value in their respective array values. However, the response(which is correct) shows two values for `base` and `ref` attributes.
Why the logged response has missing values ?

Comment: I don't suspect there's anything specific to Axios or `console.info` leading to this bug. For anyone to answer this question, they will need more information about the API and where you're calling it. You may want to double check that you're calling the exact route that you expect, and use the browser's Network dev tools to compare the response versus what is getting logged.

Comment: Also using other tools to test the API too will help to easily debug the issue.

Comment: @CalvinFurano I have compared the response from the network tab vs the one I get in console already and the same is presented in the question

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Tested the API response in postman, response is identical to the one received in my network tab

Comment: You said *”I am using axios to call my API which responds back with a response as shown below:”* so which is which then?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I'm unclear of your ask. The response of the API has already been shown in the question.

Comment: So you are saying that axios should return the first code snippet but instead you are getting the last? Is the first code snippet what the backend documented that should be received?

Comment: The question is clear in itself. The axios call responds with correct response. However, some values are missing when printed in the console. Hope now you understand

Comment: So your network tab and even postman received the first code snippet but once you log to the console, data is lost?

Comment: yes. Its not a code snippet though. A JSON response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255846/discussion-between-dragon-and-chukwujiobi-canon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was neither a fault on `axios` or `console.info`. This happens when the response from the service call is mutated anywhere from the project from where this service call was invoked. In my case it was `.splice()` method on the response array in my `index.js` file which mutated the original array reference to the response. Hence, it got affected.